Improve GPS location accuracy in Kotlin
I am developing GPS track feature using Kotlin. but when I track location and then show geolcation on google map, there is some deviation.
locationRequest = LocationRequest()
                .setInterval(120000)
                .setFastestInterval(60000)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
           override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult)

                    if (locationResult != null) {
                        val location: Location? = locationResult.lastLocation
                        if (location != null) {
                            val latitude: Double = location.getLatitude()
                            val longitude: Double = location.getLongitude()
                            ...
                     }
           }
}

 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            fusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)
        }

I think the deviation is about 5~10m. The deviation is particularly large in indoor environments.
I want to improve GPS location accuracy.

It is normal with common GPS from mobile phones. More precise? Better GPS and better antenna.  Indoor: GPS is not good: they should receive signal from GPS satellites, and calculations assume straight line. Google tracks users and AP devices (but it fails for months when an AP is moved).

GPS accuracy is completely dependent on the GPS chip and view of the sky. What you see is completely normal for a phone. If you are inside you cannot expect to get anything even remotely accurate

What about wifi? Someone said it would improve with Wi-Fi.

@DannyMay Wifi is used to triangulate the location; ie if you know the locations of the surrounding networks, network strength can be used to estimate where you are in relation to those networks. I doubt that it would be more accurate than data provided from a GPS chip. Unless you're indoors, perhaps.
